# How to include specific .jar files with pyinstaller in executable file?

Tags: java, python, jar, pyinstaller

How can I force pyinstaller to use specific .jar file when packing as exe?

I am trying to generate an executable which uses **tabula-py** lib. This library requires a jar file, **tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar**, which I have in my file.py folder. These are some modifications which are at **myfile.spec**:

```
# this is for pandas lib
def get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path = pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_path

dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)

# this is for tabula-py
jar = 'tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies'
jar_path = 'C:\\Users\\jaquedeveloper\\Documents\\freelancer\\bot\\' + jar
coll = COLLECT(exe,
       a.binaries,
       a.zipfiles,
       a.datas,
       [(jar, jar_path, 'PKG')],
       strip=None,
       upx=True,
       name='test')
```

Still, the error persists.
When I run my code from command line, the function read_pdf(), from tabula-py, which uses the java jar, works all right, perfectly.

But when I generate the executable with pyinstaller spec command, it fails to execute this function, giving the error below:

> Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\jaquedeveloper\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI58442\tabula\tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

The file is not under this folder, nor the tabula folder exists.
I have the file under the same folder of the executable file.How can I force the script to use it?
How can I import the jar from a specific path to the executable file, instead of using _MEI folder?

This issue was also repported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049391/how-to-bundle-jar-files-with-pyinstaller).

Comment: Hi Jaqueline.  Did you have any luck finding an answer to this?  I have a similar problem.

Comment: No luck, I ended up not developing the functionality due to a client request and did nothing about it since them... I have generated an exe but not using tabula, because there was no more necessity to filter the pdf files.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for letting me know. I ended up rewriting my program using Camelot-py instead of Tabula so that a user without admin rights could run it without Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I stumbled upon this thread a while ago, since I ran into the exact same Problem. Adding the .jar file to a 'onefile' executable with pyinstaller seems to place it in the wrong temporal directory - under ...AppData\Local\Temp_MEI58442\ **tabula** \tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar.
The added File seems to be placed in ...AppData\Local\Temp_MEI58442\tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar. That's why it can't be found when executing the tabula.read_pdf() command.
As a workaround I produced a onedir output with pyinstaller (instead of onefile) and added a directory 'tabula' with the jar file, and it worked.

**Bundling this into a single file also works:**
It's actually all there in the pyinstaller docs (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html). When adding the binary .jar file you can specify the relative path of the file inside the temporary folder after ':' for Linux and ';' for Win Systems. Using just '.' as path places the file under ./Temp_MEI*/. So in my case on Win it looked like this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "C:/Users/Louis/Desktop/Github/pdf_reader/venv/Lib/site-packages/tabula/tabula-1.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar;./tabula/" myapp.py
```

This solution comes a little late, but i hope it still helps somebody.

Comment: Thanks, I've used the same solution and didn't document it here. It will for sure help somebody.

Comment: I tried this fix on my debian laptop and got an error:
```pyinstaller: error: argument --add-binary: invalid add_data_or_binary value: '/home/glicka/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tabula/tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar;./tabula/'```

Do you know what I did wrong? 

My attempt:

```pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "/home/glicka/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tabula/tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar;./tabula/" src/pdf2xlsx.py
```

Comment: Might be a little too late, but if you read carefully, it says you need to use ':' instead of ';' on linux to separate dependencies

Comment: For those using conda on windows, you can find this .jar file (at least on my case, which I think is default) at

C:\Users\YourUser\.conda\pkgs\tabula-py-2.6.0-py312haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages\tabula\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar